# Using Parallelism in cython, but why no change in performance

Tags: numpy, openmp, cython, cythonize

I am learning cython by following the official cython tutorials.I had some problems when trying the section ‘Cython for NumPy users’ in Cython's Documentation.

The address is: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#numpy-tutorial

In the last example, "Using multiple threads", I tried to follow the example exactly, using jupyter notebook, but in the end the program did not run any faster. I also tried using num_threads=4 or =1, but the speed did not change either. I am confused and wonder what the reason for this is.

I am doing this in windows and I don't know if there is some special step I am missing when installing Cython or if there is something else going on.

Its code is as follows：

```
%%cython --force

import numpy as np
import timeit
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange

array_1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(3000, 2000)).astype(np.intc)
array_2 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(3000, 2000)).astype(np.intc)
a = 4
b = 3
c = 9

ctypedef fused my_type:
    int
    double
    long long

cdef my_type clip(my_type a, my_type min_value, my_type max_value) nogil:
    return min(max(a, min_value), max_value)


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def compute_cy_mt(my_type[:, ::1] array_1, my_type[:, ::1] array_2, my_type a, my_type b, my_type c):

    cdef Py_ssize_t x_max = array_1.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t y_max = array_1.shape[1]

    assert tuple(array_1.shape) == tuple(array_2.shape)

    if my_type is int:
        dtype = np.intc
    elif my_type is double:
        dtype = np.double
    elif my_type is cython.longlong:
        dtype = np.longlong

    result = np.zeros((x_max, y_max), dtype=dtype)
    cdef my_type[:, ::1] result_view = result

    cdef my_type tmp
    cdef Py_ssize_t x, y

        for y in prange(y_max, num_threads=4,nogil=True):
            tmp = clip(array_1[x, y], 2, 10)
            tmp = tmp * a + array_2[x, y] * b
            result_view[x, y] = tmp + c

    return result

print(compute_cy_mt(array_1, array_2, a, b, c))
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to pass the openmp-flag to the compiler and link against openmp, see [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#using-multiple-threads). Note that t's probably `/openmp` instead of `-fopenmp` for the MSVC Compiler on Windows.

Comment: This was indeed the cause, I have now solved it, thank you very much